# Vector of uniformly distributed random numbers in a foor-loop, Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Can someone help me with how I can create a vector, *u*, of uniformly distributed random numbers in a for-loop, so that *u* will have different sizes for each iteration in the for-loop. I mean something like this:

```
b=[100, 200, ....]; % 1x10 vector

for j=1:10

    u(j)=rand(b(j),100);

end
```

The error I get in Matlab is: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Thanks!

Comment: Because `u(j)` is a single element but `rand(b(j),100)` is big.

Comment: Yes, but do you know how I can write the code then? I want to have 10 uniformly distributed random vectors, the first 100x100, 200x100, 300x100 and so on. Then I would like to save all random vectors in one parameter *u* since later I will use it in the loop. Is this possible?

Comment: Let me introduce you to the fantastic........ Curly brakets! `u{j}`. This is called a cell array

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without a `for-loop` and using `arrayfun`.

```
b = 100:100:400;
u = arrayfun(@(x) rand(x, 100), b, 'UniformOutput', false);
```